# Find the vector, not with determinants, but by using properties of cross products

Tags: vector-spaces

$(i + j)\times(i − j)$

I know how to use the right hand rule for the cross product, but how do you find the exact vector without using determinants?

Comment: Notice that if $c=a\times b$, then $c$ lies perpendicular to the plane spanned by $a$ and $b$ and its norm equals to the area of parallelogram edged $a,b$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cross product has to be orthogonal to both $i+j$ and $i-j$. Let $v$ be this cross product. Then $\langle i+j,v\rangle=\langle i,v\rangle + \langle j,v\rangle = 0$ and $\langle i-j,v\rangle=\langle i,v\rangle - \langle j,v\rangle = 0$. What can you conclude?

Now that we know $i$ and $j$ are unit vectors, we can do a little better. If we write $v=ai+bj+ck$,
$$
\langle i,v\rangle=a,\langle j,v\rangle = b.
$$
The last fact you'll need is that $|v|=i|\cdot|j|\cdot|\sin\theta|=|\sin\theta|$. Can you figure out what the angle between $i+j$ and $i-j$ is?

Comment: isnt it incorrect to put unit vectors inside vector brackets ? and i do not follow, and you simplify, please?

Comment: Oh dear, I didn't realise these were unit vectors. Let me edit.